# Xcode compiling for a lower version iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, compilation

I have just upgraded my iOS sdk to the latest version 3.2.5 and I found that I can't install my app on my iPhone 4.1.  Is there a way that I can compile my program for the old iOS or do I need to upgrade my iPhone to 4.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had the 4.1 sdk earlier, you can set the deployment target for your app in Project->Edit Active Target->Build. Choose the "iOS Deployment Target" and set 4.1 there.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 4, set your target in the project settings like this:
[image: Screenshot of Xcode project settings]